# WPF controls being cut off behind grid cell padding(?)

Tags: wpf, xaml

apologies for the noobie question,

I have began with WPF for my XAML learning journey, and have the following window:
[XAML Preview (Flawless)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bZ6N8.png)
But when running, it looks like this:
[Result when running](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IZAgB.png)
[Markup below]

What in my markup is causing this? I could stretch the window out but I feel like that's cheating and I should know what's causing this to truly understand XAML/WPF..

Also, I've been trying to follow good practises, any feedback on "proper" coding practises would be greatly appreciated :) Thank youu

Markup:

```
<Window x:Class="xamlFun.NET8.NewTimeLine"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        ResizeMode="NoResize"
        Title="NewTimeLineGrid" Height="223" Width="688" WindowStyle="ToolWindow">
    <Border Padding="10" Margin="0,0,0,2">
        <Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="110*" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="105*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="110*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="150*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="150*"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition/>
                <RowDefinition/>
                <RowDefinition Height="60"/>
                <RowDefinition/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

            <!---Col 0 Row 0-->
            <StackPanel  Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0">
                <Label Content="Start Time" Margin="0 5" />
                <TextBox Name="txtStartTime" Height="20" Width="50" Margin="0 10" TabIndex="0" />
            </StackPanel>
            <!---Col 1 Row 0-->
            <StackPanel  Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1">
                <Label Content="Duration" Margin="0 5" />
                <TextBox Name="txtDuration" Height="20" Width="50" Margin="0 10" TabIndex="1" />
            </StackPanel>
            <!---Col 2 Row 0-->
            <StackPanel  Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2">
                <Label Content="End Time" Margin="0 5" />
                <TextBox Name="txtEndTime" Height="20" Width="50" Margin="0 10" TabIndex="2" />
            </StackPanel>
            <!---Col 3 Row 0-->
            <StackPanel  Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="3">
                <Label Content="LogIT Call" Margin="0 5" />
                <TextBox Name="txtLogit" Height="20" Width="80" Margin="0 10" TabIndex="3" />
            </StackPanel>
            <!---Col 4 Row 0-->
            <StackPanel  Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="4">
                <Label Content="User" Margin="0 5" />
                <TextBox Name="txtUser" Height="20" Width="100" Margin="0 10" TabIndex="3" />
            </StackPanel>
            <!---Col 0 Row 1-->
            <StackPanel  Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="3">
                <Label Content="Client" Margin="0 5" />
                <TextBox Name="txtClient" Height="20" Width="100" Margin="0 10" TabIndex="3" />
            </StackPanel>
            <!---Col 2 Row 1-->
            <StackPanel  Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="3" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
                <Label Content="Activiy" Margin="0 5" />
                <TextBox Name="txtActivity" Height="20" Width="100" Margin="0 10" TabIndex="3" />
            </StackPanel>
            <!--Col 0 Row 2-->
            <StackPanel  Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="5">
                <Label Content="Note" Margin="0 5" />
                <TextBox Name="txtNote" Height="40" Margin="0 10" TabIndex="3" Width="600" MaxLines="2" />
            </StackPanel>
            <!--Col 3 Row 3-->
            <StackPanel  Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="3" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Margin="10">
                <Button Name="btnSave" Click="btnSave_Click"  Content="Save" Margin="5 0 5 0" Padding="15 0 15 0"></Button>
                <Button Name="btnCancel" Click="btnCancel_Click" Content="Cancel" Margin="5 0 5 0" Padding="15 0 15 0"></Button>
            </StackPanel>
        </Grid>
    </Border>
</Window>
```

I've tried resizing, which works but isn't what I'm after. I've twiddled with padding, margin and other similar knobs but the difference between the preview and the final isn't making this very easy to figure out..

Comment: It looks like your Window is simply not heigh enough to accommodate the elements properly. Either change the size or wrap the content into a ScrollViewer. You can set the Window.SizeToContent property e.g. to Height to allow the Window to choose the best size in order to display the content.

Comment: Instead of configuring each TextBox individually you should create a Style: this saves work especially when you want to change the layout e.g. change the Margin. You would only have to change it in a single place: the Style. Also consider choosing TextBlock over the Label. It performs better (especially when binding to string values)

Comment: Set RowDefinitions' Height to Auto and remove TextBoxs' Heights.

Comment: Thanks for the responses, all very helpful and I'll see what works best for me.. Thanks for informing me of these different techniques I'll definitely look deeper into this.

Answer (score 0):

Increasing the size of the window from 223 to 250 solves your issue. The window height is quite small that it couldn't accommodate the elements.

[image: Output after increasing the height]